# R: Automatically Creating Graphs from Dataframes

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data set (route_1):

```
 route_1

  id      long      lat
1  1 -74.56048 40.07051
3  3 -72.44129 41.71506
4  4 -77.53908 41.55434
2  2 -74.23018 40.12929
6  6 -78.68685 42.35981
5  5 -79.26506 43.22408
```

Based on this data, I want to make a directed network graph in which each row is only linked to the row that comes right after. Using the "igraph" library, I was able to do this manually:

```
library(igraph)

my_data <- data.frame(

"node_a" = c("1", "3", "4", "2", "6"),
"node_b" = c("3", "4", "2", "6", "5")
)

graph <- graph.data.frame(my_data, directed=TRUE)
graph <- simplify(graph)

plot(graph)
```

[image]

**My Question:** Is it possible to make this above network graph directly using the "route_1" dataset, and without manually creating a new data set that contains information on which node is connected to what node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the dataset always going to be ordered correctly, so the plot will go from row 1->2->3 etc in a single line? If so, we can make the node info dataframe by simply subsetting the ID column. If we put the steps in a function, it becomes a simple 1-liner:

```
plot_nodes <- function(x) {
    id = x$id
    a = id[1:length(id)-1]
    b = id[2:length(id)]
    graph.data.frame(data.frame(a,b), directed=TRUE)
}

graph <- plot_nodes(route_1)
plot(simplify(graph))
```

[image]